# Distinguish comment flag from comment being flagged

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, moderator-tools, comment-flags

I once handled a flag on a post as such:

[image]

I first thought they were two separate flags, but after looking at the flag dashboard, only the first thing was a comment flag and the other was the actual comment being flagged.

For such comment flags, I think that the comment text needs to stand out in such a way that it doesn't look like it's a flag itself. Perhaps the comment should be indented and put in italics or a quote box and with the commenter listed at the end for consistency.